# find index of character in string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string-array, myString = '  23.654 ' and a character, Char = '.'. Is there some way to use the find function to determine the index of Char in myString?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) which will identify the locations where one string exists within another.

```
index = strfind(myString, '.')
```

Or you could use `==` combined with `find`. The `==` performs an element-wise equality check between each character in the string and your character of interest. It will yield a logical array that is `true` where the character occurs, and `false` otherwise. If you need the actual index, `find` will return the location of all of the `true` values.

```
index = find(myString == '.')
```